# Drupal 7 Panels Sharing Data Between Panes

Tags: drupal-7, share, panels, panes

I have a bunch of custom content types I've created for Drupal 7 Panels module. Everything works perfectly.  I'm wondering if there's a way to share data between my panes.  For example, I've got my layout setup so that on the right side there are a few panes that form a sidebar.  I want to pass data from one sidebar pane to another.  Is there an overall "Page" variable that I can store data in so that any pane on the page can access it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the panel page's context settings to expose various contexts, and then use custom content panes, enable the replacement patterns, and use those patterns with custom panes.

If you are using views for any of this content, you can use panel contexts as arguments for the views as well.